# Installing Lync 2013 sdk client side on visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, lync-2013, lync-client-sdk

I am trying to install the Lync 2013 SDK on Visual studio 2015, but I get an error saying "MSVS2010 SP1 or higher not found. Go here to download and install"

I've looked up the issue on the web, and the closest thing to a solution is installing a cumulative update, but that was for VS2013, nor can I find any Place to actually download the file.

What do I have to do to complete the Lync 2013 SDK setup?

Comment: This question seems more suited for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions).

Answer (score 4):

To install the SDK, you can fake that you have an earlier version of Visual Studio. At least, that seemed to work for me.

What I did was export the registry entries at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Setup\vs`, searched and replaced `VisualStudio\14.0` with `VisualStudio\12.0` and imported those registry entries again.

That allowed me to install the SDK and I subsequently removed those imported entries again.
Please make sure (using `regedit`) that you are not overwriting any existing entries of course.

Comment: Works nicely with VS2015

Comment: Also see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35934759/552448) Use Universal Extractor or a similar tool to unpack the SDK kit, then use the appropriate MSI.