# Develop with Lync 2013 SDK on Visual Studio 2015 Community?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, lync-2013, skype-for-business, lync-client-sdk

Does VS2015 have any restriction regarding developing Skype for business (Lync 2013 SDK) applications?

When I try to install the Lync 2013 SDK I get an error saying "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1 or higher not found."

Do I need a Enterprise version?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this problem related to MS bug.
You have to unpack it and try to install 64 or 86 msi package.[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are no restrictions.  I developed my first application in C# and the Lync 2013 SDK using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.